# An alternative term for 'lesser time'

Tags: synonyms, time, comparatives

I have two processes running with different speeds. In other words, one of them requires lesser time. I think 'Lesser time' is an awkward term. Is there any good alternative or synonym which I can use instead of 'lesser time'?

Comment: Do you mean it requires less time to complete, in which case a simple **faster** will suffice?

Comment: Different speeds == some go faster == require less time? I don't know what you mean by "process" in this context, whether you're talking about mutli-threaded programming or something else.

Comment: Thank you, so 'lesser time' is not a common term and i should reverse my sentence to use something such as faster. My sentence is 'we can find more vulnerabilities in lesser time'. Can I use something like 'a smaller portion of time'?

Comment: Your sentence would be fine if you just changed "lesser" to "less".

Comment: You could use "less time," "a shorter period of time" or "faster," but not "lesser time."

Comment: Following @MorganFR comment: or "more quickly".  "Faster" & "more quickly" mean the same, but there are places where one seems correct & the other sounds odd (at least in BrE).

Comment: This question may be more appropriate on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: *Less* is already a comparative so you don't normally need to add *..er*. However *lesser* has an adjectival sense of its own in certain idioms e.g. a *lesser offence*, or *a lesser charge*. But if there is a grammarian in the vicinity I would be interested to hear the full explanation myself.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of programming, you can say one process is more efficient than the other because of **less time complexity.**

Comment: Can you please explain what that means?  It doesn't make sense to me in British English!  How can time be more or less complex?

Comment: In simple terms, Time complexity of an algorithm signifies the total time required by the program to run to completion.In your question you have described about two different processes(which I am assuming to be computer/software process) taking different amount of time i.e. different time complexity.

Comment: Good approach here. 'Time complexity ' is different from the time you'd measure on a stopwatch. Run a program on a very slow computer and it will take a long time, run it on a fast computer and it will take less time, but the program is just as complex on both machines and need to do the same amount of expensive 'thinking'